# What is the relation between Java KeyStore (JKS) and key types it can store

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, jks, key-pair

I am trying to identify a proper way how to list all supported cryptographic key types, sizes, and hashing functions, for a particular Java KeyStore.

According to the [JDK Providers Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-FE2D2E28-C991-4EF9-9DBE-2A4982726313), there are different providers that offer various implementation of the services and algorithms.

I do not understand what is the relation of the `KeyStore` type, in my case it is `JKS` (by `SUN` provider), and the key types it can store. According to the documentation the `SUN` provider can work only with `DSA` key pair, however I am able to store `RSA` or `EC` key pairs in the `JKS` provided by `SUN` provider.

How can I know which key pair types particular `KeyStore` type can store and manage? Is there any documentation or description about that? Is the `KeyStore` just storage facility with the particular implementation and protection and does not depend what key pair type generated by which provider is stored inside?

My goal is to take the `KeyStore`, and based on its properties list all supported cryptographic algorithms, key sizes, and hashing function that can be used to generate key pair and sign the data.

> An example: I have the `JKS` `KeyStore` provided by `SUN` provider. It can contain `DSA`, `RSA`, `EC` key pairs. For `RSA`, it can support from `512` to `16384` bits long keys and `SHA1withRSA`, `SHA256withRSA`,... and similar for the other key types.

Because I am loading `KeyStore` dynamically and I do not know before that its provider (I am using the `keytool` command), I am looking for a proper way how to dynamically load all supported algorithms based on the supported providers.

Comment: You're talking about **algorithms** not types. The _types_ of entries JKS can store are PrivateKey (which also contains the cert/chain thus the public key) and TrustedCert (which contains a public key) but not SecretKey. Yes PrivateKey or TrustedCert can _contain_ any key algorithm for which a provider is available -- in the 'standard' Oracle or OpenJDK package this is DSA RSA EC as you say, plus Ed25519 and Ed448 in 15 up, but in modified or other builds or environments it may differ. A _certificate_ uses a signature algorithm like SHA256withRSA but a _key_ does not.

Comment: Also note support for EC curves has good down over recent versions, so you may have a keystore containing an EC key and a Java that supports EC but nevertheless can't use the key. Finally if you want security you shouldn't be using JKS at all, but if you are letting user(s) choose crypto algorithms and parameters, which it sounds like, you clearly don't care about security because decades of experience proves that one of the fastest ways to destroy security.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, the JKS is one example, the same applies for other types of the KeyStore like JCEKS, BKS, etc. If I understand your comment properly, the PrivateKey provider is independent of the KeyStore provider and therefore I can have for example JKS KeyStore and inside I can generate RSA key using the BouncyCastle provider. Is my understanding correct? I can use any provider capable of working with the key type and store it in any KeyStore type?

Comment: For _asymmetric_ keys yes as I said PrivateKey or TrustedCert can contain key(s) for any algorithm(s) for which a provider is available. _Symmetric_ keys are only supported by some keystore types, and I've run into cases that didn't work for cipher algorithm(s) which didn't need and didn't implement SecretKeyFactory.